# Ethers Required for Test Net

Tags: ether, testnets

I need 100 ETH for My Ropsen Test net account. Can any one please send ETH to my wallet, I am ready to exchange for Fiat Currency?

Thanks
Amit Modi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a faucet like [this one](https://ethtools.com/ropsten/tools/faucet/).

A video outlining its usage can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoxxZD9afpk).

You do not need 100 Ether. Transaction gas costs a negligible amount of Ether.

Why would you pay for testnet Ether? It has no value.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for your Guide lines. I need 100 ETH for testing few things with my smart contracts. I would love to pay as I can't wait to mine them, I need them urgently for let my development work go.

Comment: Transactions to execute smart contracts cost less than 0.01 Ether. The Faucet above will give you 5 Ether every 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Rinkeby test net and it has been working fine for me. (better than Ropsten)
It's free, you don't have to pay anything.

Steps:

1. Install the metamask plugin from the chrome store.
2. After you create an account, select the rinkeby testnet from the top

[image]

1. Press the BUY button & you would see the below screen,
   [image]
2. Press the "RINKEBY TEST FAUCET" button and you browser would open the Rinkeby site.
3. Now press the button on the left panel called "Crypto Faucet".
4. A screen would display asking for your Ethereum address. The catch here is that you would need to create a gist on **github** with your address in it and paste the **gist url**  here.
5. After pasting the gist url and pressing the 'Give me Ether" button, you would be rewarded the ether in your account.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Ajay

Comment: Thanks Ajay. But I want to work on Ropsen Test Net only.